# Why does Assuming for Integrate not work as expected?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I'm trying to perform the following integral with Mathematica 7:

```
Assuming[{t>0},
  Integrate[(-s^2 + 4*s*t + 2*alpha*s)^(-(1/2)*D),{s, 0, t}, {alpha, 0, Infinity}]]
```

If I perform the integration with just the t>0 assumption, Mathematica gives:

```
(1/(-2 + D))If[Re[D] < 2,
  ( 2^-D t^(2 - D) (
  -8 (-4 + D) Gamma[1 + D/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - D/2, D/2, 2 - D/2, 1/4]
  + (-2 + D) D Gamma[D/2] Hypergeometric2F1[2 - D/2, D/2, 3 - D/2, 1/4]
  ))/((-4 + D) (-2 + D) Gamma[1 + D/2]),
  Integrate[(-s (s - 4 t))^(1 - D/2)/s, {s, 0, t}, Assumptions -> Re[D] >= 2 && t > 0]]
```

which indicates that D must be less than 2. If I now use the additional assumption `D<2` with `Assuming[{t>0,D<2},` Mathematica says that the integral no longer converges. (Also with exchanged places for the integration variables, the integral can no longer be calculated).

Can anyone solve the mystery?

Thanks, Tobias

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this will give you a result : `Simplify[Integrate[(-s^2 + 4*s*t + 2*alpha*s)^(-(1/2)*bigD), {s, 0, 
   t}, {alpha, 0, Infinity}], Assumptions -> {bigD < 2}]`.

Comment: Please note that `D` is a reserved word

Comment: Thanks, it looks like assumptions work differently when used directly in Integrate or with Assuming[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really diverges.

I'll start with integrating over `s`. You actually integrate over `alpha`, so if this is a case where Fubini's theorem does not hold then this analysis might be wrong.

```
Integrate[(-s^2 + 4*s*t + 2*alpha*s)^(-(1/2)*d), {s, 0, t}, 
  Assumptions -> {t > 0, alpha > 0}]

(* ConditionalExpression[(2 alpha + 4 t)^(1 - d)
   Beta[t/(2 alpha + 4 t), 1 - d/2, 1 - d/2], Re[d] < 2] *)
```

This shows (as you knew) that we require `d<2`. So let's see where that takes us.

```
i1 = Integrate[(-s^2 + 4*s*t + 2*alpha*s)^(-(1/2)*d), {s, 0, t}, 
   Assumptions -> {t > 0, d < 2, alpha > 0}];
```

We can check behavior at the endpoints to assess convergence.

```
sinf = 
 Normal[Series[i1, {alpha, Infinity, 2}, 
   Assumptions -> {t > 0, d < 2, alpha > 0}]]

(* Out[102]= (alpha/t)^(d/2) (alpha + 2 t)^(
 1 - d) (-((2^(1 - d/2) t)/(alpha (-2 + d))) - (
   2^(-1 - d/2) (-16 + 5 d) t^2)/(alpha^2 (-4 + d))) *)
```

If you look closely you will see that the lead term in `alpha` is of magnitude `alpha^(d/2)*alpha^(1-d)*alpha^(-1)`. This comes to `alpha^(-d)`. Since `d<2` this means we won't have convergence at infinity.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This was not my main question though. With b.gatessucks' Simplify-Assumptions I get a result, if I use these assumptions for Integrate itself or use them with Assuming I get the no-convergence error.

This is also interesting, since when one performs the integrations one by one starting with s first, it only converges for d<2, starting with alpha, it only converges for d>2. Still mathematica gives a result for d<2 with the Simplify-Assumptions method.

Comment: This might indeed be a case where Fubinis theorem does not hold, though the s-integral appears here in my problem "naturally" as the outer one (understood as iterated integrals). I will have to think about this more.

Comment: There is a subtlety that account for getting a result with assumptions. It is that multiple integrals do very little to assess convergence other than in the final integration. If you instead do Simplify[Integrate[(-s^2 + 4*s*t + 2*alpha*s)^(-(1/2)*bigD), {s, 0, 
   t}, {alpha, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {bigD < 2}, 
  GenerateConditions -> True], Assumptions -> {bigD < 2}] you will again get a divergence.