# How to deal with units in logarithms?

Tags: units, chemistry

I'm trying to take a formula, take it's integral which yields a formula with logarithms, and then directly plug in values with units and get an answer. However if the units go into any of the logarithms I get conditional expressions. Is it possible to set up the equations so I can just plug in units?

Here's my code:

```
Pideal[n_, T_, V_] := (n*R*T)/V
PvdW[n_, T_, V_, a_: a, b_: b] := (n*R*T)/(V - n*b) - (n^2*a)/V^2
W[V1_, V2_, P_] := Integrate[P, {V, V1, V2}]
Wideal[V1_, V2_, n_: n, T_: T] = W[V1, V2, Pideal[n, T, V]]
```

Here's the problem spot:

```
Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]
```

I can work around this fairly easily, just leave out the Liters because they cancel out anyway. (`Liters = Quantity["Liters"]`, etc)

However when I get to a more complicated equation that doesn't work so easily without making sure to put back in what I leave out.

```
WvdW[V1_, V2_, n_: n, T_: T, a_: a, b_: b] = 
    W[V1, V2, PvdW[n, T, V, a, b]]
WvdW[5*Liters, 10*Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins, 0, 0]
```

This doesn't work for the same reason, even though the Liters cancel out Mathematica doesn't assume that. However if I leave them out, I still have problems with the Mols, which appear in and outside of Logarithms, even though they're multiplied by 0.

```
WvdW[5, 10, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins, 0, 0]
```

Finally, I haven't even gotten to using b which also appears in the logarithm, and even though the volumes add up and cancel out, Mathematica doesn't assume so.

```
WvdW[V1*Liters, V2*Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins, 0, 0 Mols Liters^(-1)]
```

Comment: Side note: You should not use custom function names beginning with capital letters, which might conflict with the built-in function names.

Comment: If you define your functions with `SetDelayed` ( `:=` ) instead of `Set` ( `=`) you don't appear to have a problem whatsoever.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The calculation goes through, however then the units come out wrong. For example Wideal should be in units of Joules, and using SetDelayed gives an answer in units of meters^2 Joules.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't define the units of R? With `R = Quantity["MolarGasConstant"]` and `UnitConvert[
 Wideal[Quantity [5, "Liters"], Quantity [10, "Liters"], 
  Quantity [1, "Moles"], Quantity[ 298, "Kelvins"]], "Joules"]` I get `Quantity[1.71742, "Joules"]`.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `Assumptions` in one form or another.

```
Block[{$Assumptions = Liters > 0 && Mols > 0 && Kelvins > 0}, 
 Simplify[Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]]
 ]
(* -> 298 Kelvins Mols R Log[2] *)
```

One disappointment for me is that the following doesn't work:

```
Block[{$Assumptions = Liters > 0 && Mols > 0 && Kelvins > 0}, 
 Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]
 ]
(* -> ConditionalExpression[298 Kelvins Mols R (-Log[5 Liters] + Log[10 Liters]), Liters != 0] *)
```

Nor does putting the assumptions directly in the `Integrate`:

```
W[V1_, V2_, P_] := Integrate[P, {V, V1, V2}, Assumptions :> Liters > 0 && Mols > 0 && Kelvins > 0];
Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]
(* -> ConditionalExpression[298 Kelvins Mols R (-Log[5 Liters] + Log[10 Liters]), Liters != 0] *)
```

It seems using `Simplify` is necessary.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration/19894#19894) for more on `Integrate` and assumptions.

**Update**

I think Silvia has made the best point, that the units should be canceled out first.  Simply using `SetDelayed` lets `Integrate` cancel the units in the given example.  If there are cases where one might have to use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` first, then remove the comments.

```
Pideal[n_, T_, V_] := (n*R*T)/V;
PvdW[n_, T_, V_, a_: a, b_: b] := (n*R*T)/(V - n*b) - (n^2*a)/V^2;
W[V1_, V2_, P_] := Integrate[(*Simplify@*)P, {V, V1, V2}];
Wideal[V1_, V2_, n_: n, T_: T] := W[V1, V2, Pideal[n, T, V]];

Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]
(* -> 298 Kelvins Mols R Log[2] *)
```

Comment: If I ever see one of my students writing `Liters > 0` I swear s/he'd be better starting to run away very fast (+1)

Comment: @belisarius, @teratoma My reaction to the title question was you can't plug units into a logarithm, but in fact the units cancel out.  I do have a historical/philosophical reason for choosing `Liters > 0`, although it stretches a point and does not quite fit with modern concepts.  As magnitudes, units are more than nothing, and real numbers were invented, at least in part, to represent ratios of magnitudes. To work with expressions such as `Sqrt[Meter^2]`, one (implicitly) assumes that units behave as if they're positive real numbers.

Comment: Just in case, that wasn't a critic but pretended to be an hilarious comment. Sometimes I keep the emoticons out because "a buen entendedor, pocas palabras"

Comment: @belisarius Thanks.  That's how I understood it.  But also I had thought about that issue already.  Having taught courses in ancient mathematics - before real numbers were invented to measure magnitudes - I did have some reasons for thinking `Liters > 0` is the best choice.  Much less absurd than, say, `Liters \[Element] Reals`.  And, you know, when one has thought about something, it's hard not to tell it.  Call it "sharing" or "showing off", it doesn't matter much to me.  If we didn't do it, we wouldn't learn as much from each other.

Comment: That's the pleasure we most enjoy here: hearing thoughts :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Clear[Wideal]
Wideal[V1_, V2_, n_: n, T_: T] := Evaluate[W[V1, V2, Pideal[n, T, V]]] // FullSimplify

Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]
```

> ```
> 298 Kelvins Mols R Log[2]
> ```

```
Clear[WvdW]
WvdW[V1_, V2_, n_ : n, T_ : T, a_ : a, b_ : b] := 
 Evaluate[(Integrate[PvdW[n, T, V, a, b], V] /. {{V -> V1}, {V -> V2}}).{-1, 1}] // FullSimplify

WvdW[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins, 0, 0]
```

> ```
> 298 Kelvins Mols R Log[2]
> ```

(Don't know why, `Integrate[-((a n^2)/V^2) + (n R T)/(-b n + V), {V, V1, V2}]` feels taking forever on my laptop..)

Like Michael pointed out, additional assumptions may be needed for more complex expressions.

## comment

I think a better way is to cancel the units before the quantity is feed to logarithm, because it's ill-defined of a logarithm with a parameter whose unit is other than $1$. (Think of the Taylor expansion of logarithm!) So the built-in **Units** functions might be a better choice than custom definitions. (Or simply do not involve units in calculations.)

Comment: I tried `Units` and the answer has a factor `-Log[Quantity[5, "Liters"]] + Log[Quantity[10, "Liters"]]`, so Mathematica doesn't mind taking `Log` of a liter.  Any fix?

Comment: @MichaelE2 [Sjoerd's comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20075/how-to-deal-with-units-in-logarithms/20078#comment61729_20075) looks working for me. But for simplifying `Log[...] + Log[...]`, maybe one has to define some custom `TransformationFunctions`.

Comment: It works with `SetDelayed` (`Wideal[...]:=...`) instead of the original `Set`.  I had tried it with the original code.

Comment: (+1) For the very last sentence in parentheses. I remember this units business in logarithms was very common in chemistry labs. But it's an ugly thing to have in any calculation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I ended with something like this: `Log[Quantity[5, "Liters"]] (Quantity[-298, "Kelvins" "MolarGasConstant" "Moles"]) + Quantity[0, ("Kilograms" ("Meters")^5)/("Liters" ("Seconds")^2)] + Log[Quantity[10, "Liters"]] (Quantity[298, "Kelvins" "MolarGasConstant" "Moles"]) /. Plus[c1_ Log[a_], c2_ Log[b_]] /; Abs[QuantityMagnitude[c1]] == Abs[QuantityMagnitude[c2]] :> Plus[Quantity[Abs[QuantityMagnitude[c1]], QuantityUnit[c1]] Log[ a^Sign[QuantityMagnitude[c1]] b^Sign[QuantityMagnitude[c2]]]] // UnitConvert[#, "Joules"] &`, very ugly..

Comment: @Jens Thanks. I'm not familiar with chemistry, but I believe, when doing complex physics calculations, people usually go without units, except for [dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Comment: @Silvia You're definitely right when it comes to computational physics. There's also a difference between keeping track of *dimensions* and using *units*. Even in dimensional analysis, the central role is really played by the *dimensionless* quantities that one can construct. Unit support in computer algebra may be a matter of taste, but this Q&A seems to show how absurd it can get...

Comment: @Jens Absurd it is! I think the unit support is mainly aimed on high school educations.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be the `Integrate` result: as usual it assumes all variables could be complex which results in a complicated `ConditionalExpression` which will not evaluate correctly when fed with variables that have units. The trick is, as Michael has shown to use assumptions, but I think it is much better to use the assumptions for the formal variables than for the units, it's not only belisarius students who probably shouldn't do that :-). To see the problem evaluate this:

```
Integrate[Pideal[n, T, V], {V, V1, V2}
```

Now if you are not working in very unusual conditions it might be safe to assume that `V1` and `V2` both are real valued and larger than zero:

```
Integrate[Pideal[n, T, V], {V, V1, V2}, Assumptions -> {V1 > 0, V2 > 0}]
```

which makes the result already a lot simpler, but still is a `ConditionalExpression` which should also evaluate for variables with units. For some reasons out of my understanding Mathematica seems to be too restrictive here, as it only returns a result for `V1 < V2`, but of course we know that the result is exactly the same for `V2 < V1`, and Mathematica also knows that:

```
Integrate[Pideal[n, T, V], {V, V1, V2},Assumptions -> {V1 > 0, 0 < V2 < V1}]
Integrate[Pideal[n, T, V], {V, V1, V2},Assumptions -> {V1 > 0, 0 < V1 < V2}]
```

so for this case you wouldn't actually need a `ConditionalExpression` at all (I think that `Log` will even give the correct results for most "academic corner cases", that is when one or two of `V1,V2` will be zero). Putting all this together you could use something like the following:

```
Liters = Quantity["Liters"];
Kelvins = Quantity["Kelvins"];
Mols = Quantity["Moles"];
Pideal[n_, T_, V_] := (n*R*T)/V
PvdW[n_, T_, V_, a_: a, b_: b] := (n*R*T)/(V - n*b) - (n^2*a)/V^2
W[V1_, V2_, P_] := Piecewise[{
   {Integrate[P, {V, V1, V2}, Assumptions -> V1 > V2 > 0], V1 > V2},
   {Integrate[P, {V, V1, V2}, Assumptions -> V2 > V1 > 0], V2 > V1}
   }, Indeterminate]
Wideal[V1_, V2_, n_: n, T_: T] = W[V1, V2, Pideal[n, T, V]];

Wideal[5 Liters, 10 Liters, 1 Mols, 298 Kelvins]
```

Given the above definitions you'll receive an answer which does evaluate correctly and I don't think it is a problem to feed quantities (with units) to those expressions: if the units don't match and the argument to the `Log` isn't dimensionless, you'll get a partially unevaluated result and some messages, which might even help you to find problems related to wrong units... There remains one problem: if you need to use another definition for the equation of state you might need to check whether and which assumptions you have to give to `Integrate`...