# Is this result wrong because of calculation time? (and more questions about Assumptions)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am confused with the Integrate Given by *Mathematica*. First let's see a one-dimensional case:

```
    Integrate[UnitStep[k - Sqrt[kx^2]], {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> k > 0]
```

The result is `2k`. Right answer! You can change `UnitStep` to `HeavisideTheta`, it still gives the same correct answer.

However, when changing to three dimension case,`HeavisideTheta` gives the wrong answer. See the following:

```
Integrate[ HeavisideTheta[k - Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]],
  {kx,-Infinity,  Infinity}, {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kz, -Infinity, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> k > 0]
```

*Mathematica* gives the wrong answer `0` and with an error message I don't understand.

> Refine::fas: Warning: One or more assumptions evaluated to False.

If `Assumptions` is not added, it directly gives `0` without any WARNING! As if it calculated it right! How dangerous if I previously didn't know the answer!

@Jens suggested using `UnitStep` instead of `HeavisideStep`. I tried: in *Mathematica* 7 it fails (giving the wrong answer 0) but in version 8 it gives the right result:

```
    (4 k^3 \[Pi])/3
```

Still with the same message:

> Refine::fas: Warning: One or more assumptions evaluated to False.

### So what does this message mean? Why do different *Mathematica* versions give different answers? Is this because of the computing time involved?

---

Above is the main question, here is some subtle question I would like to ask; see this integral:

```
Assuming[k > 0, Integrate[ UnitStep[k - Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]],
  {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}, {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kz, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

the results:

```
    (4 k^3 \[Pi])/3 k>0
     0  True
```

### It seems *Mathematica* 'forgets' that I have assumed that `k>0`. Why is that? What does the second line of the result mean?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE!  Please note that formatted code does not wrap lines.  Please include returns as appropriate to make the question more readable.  (Thanks!)

Comment: FYI, in v9.0.1, I get no warning messages with `UnitStep`, just the correct answer. With `Assumptions -> k > 0`, I get a more detailed message that shows `kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2` has been factored;  adding `kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2 > 0` to the assumptions removes the message, but the output is still 0.  With `Assuming`, I get the output `-(4/3) k^3 \[Pi] (-1 + UnitStep[-k])`, which is cute.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration

Comment: Can you answer my second bold face question?
And, can you tell me why mathematica can calculate 1D but not 3D, is this because computation time?

Comment: I don't know the answer to why the assumption is forgotten, but I've observed it before.  Others have asked before, but I can't find a suitable answer to refer you to (sorry!).  As for the result, it looks like a [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) function, that is 0 in the default case (when `k > 0` is false).