# Simplify $\cos(n \pi)$ and $\sin(n \pi)$ when n is an integer

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I was trying to calculate this integral in *Mathematica 9*:

```
2/π Integrate[ Cosh[a x] Cos[n x], {x, 0, π}, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

I got as a result :

$$\frac{2 (a \sinh (\pi  a) \cos (\pi  n)+n \cosh (\pi  a) \sin (\pi  n))}{\pi  \left(a^2+n^2\right)}$$

That's the same result I obtained manually, but how can I force *Mathematica* to change $\sin(n \pi)$ into $0$ and $\cos(n \pi)$ into $(-1)^n$ ?

Comment: Did you already try `Assuming[Element[n, Integers], 
 2/Pi Integrate[Cosh[a x] Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}]]`?

Comment: Thank you, it does work indeed, what's wrong with the form I used ? (`Assumptions -> ...`) Maybe you could post this as an answer so I can award you the points

Comment: I'm not quite sure why one works and the other doesn't, even though they are ostensibly equivalent; the reason I left a comment is because I am not at a machine with *Mathematica*. Might I suggest writing your own answer to your own question instead?

Comment: I'm on it, thank you for the help !

Comment: You can do it also this way: `Simplify[2/Pi Integrate[Cosh[a x] Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}], Element[n, Integers]]`, it should work in more general cases than your original problem.

Comment: If someone does know why the original one doesn't work, please post it :)

Comment: @Lucas See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration/19894#19894).  Perhaps this question is a duplicate?  (It's sort of the other side of the coin.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. I think they are sufficiently different, though a comment in one of the answers implies there are yet more that refer to the same behaviour (bug, IMO).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to J. M. and Artes, I figured out what the problem was.

I had to change

```
2/π Integrate[ Cosh[a x] Cos[n x], {x, 0, π}, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

into

```
Assuming[ n ∈ Integers, 2/π Integrate[ Cosh[a x] Cos[n x], {x, 0, π}]]
```

or

```
Simplify[ 2/π Integrate[ Cosh[a x] Cos[n x], {x, 0, π}], n ∈ Integers]
```

I don't know what's the problem with the first form but still, it works !

Comment: If you set the assumptions outside the scope of `Integrate[]`, that is inside `Assuming[]` or `Simplify[]` then `Integrate[]` doesn't mess with them. That is how I understand it. Check this link also. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration/19894#19894