# strange result with trigonometric triple integral

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm defining functions

```
    e[k_, t_] := Cos[Pi (k - 1) t]
    cosIntRaw[k_, l_, m_] := Integrate[e[k, t] e[l, t] e[m, t], {t, 0, 1}]
    cosInt[k_, l_, m_] := 
       Assuming[Element[{k, l, m}, Integers], Refine[cosIntRaw[k, l, m]]]
```

The value that Mathematica gives me for `cosInt[k,l,m]` is `0`.

But explicitly evaluating `cosInt[1, 1, 1]`, I get `1`.  In fact, for any given value of `m`, the number of nonzero elements in the `n`$\times$`n` matrix whose `[k,l]` element is `cosInt[k,l,m]` grows linearly in `n`, said matrix having a nice banded structure.

Any idea why Mathematica gives me `0` for `cosInt[k,l,m]`?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is covered in posts at the links [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48560/inconsistent-behavior-of-assuming-in-combination-with-simplify), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743774/proper-way-to-simplify-integral-result-in-mathematica-given-integer-constraints), [4](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Feb/msg00667.html), and probably several others. Given that a couple of these are from MSE, I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
e[k_, t_] := Cos[Pi (k - 1) t];

cosIntRaw[k_, l_, m_] :=
  Integrate[e[k, t] e[l, t] e[m, t], {t, 0, 1}];

cosIntRaw[k, l, m] // Simplify
```

> -((Sin[(k - l - m)*Pi]/
>              (1 + k - l - m) + 
>            Sin[(k + l - m)*Pi]/
>              (-1 + k + l - m) + 
>            Sin[(k - l + m)*Pi]/
>              (-1 + k - l + m) + 
>            Sin[(k + l + m)*Pi]/
>              (-3 + k + l + m))/(4*Pi))

The Sin functions are all zero at integer multiples of Pi, i.e., for {k, l, m} all integers.

```
cosInt[k_, l_, m_] = 
 Assuming[Element[{k, l, m}, Integers], Simplify[cosIntRaw[k, l, m]]]
```

> 0

cosIntRaw[1,1,1] is indeterminate (division by zero); however, the limits exist.

```
Limit[cosIntRaw @@ #, a -> 1] & /@ Permutations[{a, 1, 1}]
```

> {1, 1, 1}

```
Limit[cosIntRaw @@ #, a -> 1] & /@ Permutations[{a, a, 1}]
```

> {1, 1, 1}

```
Limit[cosIntRaw[a, a, a], a -> 1]
```

> 1

These limits are essentially taken when the value substitutions are made prior to integration

```
Integrate[e[1, t] e[1, t] e[1, t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

> 1

Alternatively, rewrite cosIntRaw in terms of Sinc functions to handle the limits

```
cosIntRaw[k_, l_, m_] = (cosIntRaw[k, l, m] /. Sin[x_] :> x*Sinc[x]) // 
  Simplify
```

> 1/4 (Sinc[(1 + k - l - m) [Pi]] + Sinc[(-1 + k + l - m) [Pi]] + 
>      Sinc[(-1 + k - l + m) [Pi]] + Sinc[(-3 + k + l + m) [Pi]])

```
cosIntRaw[1, 1, 1]
```

> 1