# How to get a difference of two contour integrals depending on integer parameter?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I have two following functions:

```
h[x_, a_, e_] := 
Integrate[(6^(a/2) (1 - (t + I*e))^(-a/2 - 1) Gamma[(2 + a)/2])/ 
Gamma[a/2] E^(-x*(t + I*e)), {t, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {Im[e] == 0, Re[e] > 0, Re[e] < 1, Re[x] > 0, a > 0, 
a ∈ Integers}]
```

and

```
g[x_, a_, e_] := 
Integrate[(6^(a/2) (1 - (t - I*e))^(-a/2 - 1) Gamma[(2 + a)/2])/ 
Gamma[a/2] E^(-x*(t - I*e)), {t, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {Im[e] == 0, Re[e] > 0, Re[e] < 1, Re[x] > 0, a > 0, 
a ∈ Integers}]
```

Basically, they are integrations over two different contours(2 lateral Laplace transforms). Since, there is a pole on the real axis, at t=1, the integrals should differ. But, when I check for the limit, when e goes to 0, I get

```
Limit[h[x, a, e] - g[x, a, e], e -> 0]
0
```

But, if I plug in, for example a=10, I get

```
Limit[h[x, 10, e] - g[x, 10, e], e -> 0]
648 I E^-x π x^5
```

which is also expected. How could I get a function depending generally on parameter a, without getting 0?

Comment: If you do `FullSimplify[h[x, 10, e] - g[x, 10, e], 
 Assumptions -> {0 < e < 1, Re[x] > 0}]` and then take the limit it seems to return what you expect.

Comment: @b.gatessucks for a=10 worked already before, my problem is to get function for any a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When parameters to a integral are [integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration/19894#19894), I often fall back to calculating the "general" result, make a table where the parameter is explicitly given integer values, and then feed to [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html).

In this case:

```
table = Table[h[x, a, e] - g[x, a, e], {a, 1, 11}];
limits = Limit[#, e -> 0] & /@ table;
f = FindSequenceFunction[limits];

f[a]
(* (I 2^(1 + a/2) 3^(a/2) E^-x π x^(a/2))/(-1 + a/2)! *)

f[10]
(* 648 I E^-x π x^5 *)
```

Comment: Wow, this is a nice workaround! Thank you!