# Using assumptions with Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I open *Mathematica* and execute this code:

```
Integrate[BesselJ[0, s*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> s ∈ Reals]
(* MMA can't integrate this *)

Assuming[s ∈ Reals, Integrate[BesselJ[0, s*x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]
(* Output->1/Abs[s] *)
```

Also

```
Integrate[BesselJ[0, s*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> s > 0]
(* MMA can't integrate this *)

Assuming[s > 0, Integrate[BesselJ[0, s*x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]
(* Output->1/s *)

$Version
(* 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015) *)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/

Comment: It works for me, though takes about a minute to calculate (Win7 Mma10.4.1)

Comment: @MichaelE2.  Now I am even more confused............Thanks.