# Assumptions with Multiple Rules

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

What is the correct way to add more than one assumption while integrating?

I am attempting to evaluate the following integral and Mathematica is just stalling, so I'm wondering if my assumptions are the problem:

```
 Integrate[k Sqrt[k^2 - k0^2] ((kf^2 - k^2)/k^2 Log[(kf + k)/(kf - k)]
   + 2 kf), {k, k0, Sqrt[kf^2 + k0^2] - e}, Assumptions -> {Reals, e > 0}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Reals` in the Assumptions?  That all variables appearing in the integrand are real? or that only `e` is real?

Comment: e must be Real anyway since it is greater than 0

Comment: @QuantumDot Since Assumptions->Reals means all variables involved are real, I was trying to retain that meaning while also adding the e>0 condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of Assuming for Integration](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration)

Comment: To be safe you might try to be explicit about the real variables: `Assumptions -> {k0, kf, ky} \[Element] Reals && e > 0`

Answer (score 4):

I think what you mean is

```
Assuming[a<0 && b\[Element]Reals && c==3, FullSimplify[Integrate[f[a,b,c,d], {d,e,f}]]]
```

if you have different assumptions for different variables, or with the same assumption for a bunch of variables:

```
Assuming[{a, b, c}>0 && a>b, FullSimplify[Integrate[f[a,b,c,d], {d,e,f}]]]
```

so use the [Assuming[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) and [&&](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html) commands.

The difference between the Assuming[] and the Assumptions-> command is the topic of this thread: [click](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/9256)

Comment: Two question about this: Is there a way to specify the assumption that all variables involved are real using this method, the way Assumptions->Reals does? And I thought I had read that using Assuming[a==1, ...] permanently added "a==1" to the default assumptions for further calculations until changed, so I had avoided it. Is that true or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Max, Assuming only temporarily appends to `$Assumptions` for that expression -- it won't affect further calculations. To see this, try comparing `$Assumptions` with `Assuming[x > 0, $Assumptions]` ...That said, I usually do what you did by adding an assumption to Integrate. I find that more readable.

Comment: Rashid already answered that, but for your integral there seems to be no analytical solution with the given assumptions, so you might have to use NIntegrate instead of Integrate.