# Should integrate detect orthogonality of functions in the integrand?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What would be the correct way to tell Mathematica that

```
 Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Should not be zero when `n` is an integer for all `n` in the above?  Since when `n=3` the answer should be `Pi/2` and zero for all other `n` values.

But Mathematica does not seem to detect this, even when told that `n` is integer:

```
ClearAll[x,n]
Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi},Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 % /. n -> 3
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if

```
Assuming[Element[n,Integers]&&n>0,Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x],{x,0,Pi}]]
(*0*)
```

While

```
n=3;
Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x],{x,0,Pi}]
(* Pi/2*)
```

The question is, is it the programmer responsibility to tell Mathematica that `sin(3 x)*sin(n x)` is special case when `n=3`?  May be make a function around it, something like

```
foo[n_Integer]:=
   If[n==3,
      Integrate[Sin[3 x]^2,{x,0,Pi}],
      Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x],{x,0,Pi}]] (*0*)
   ];
```

But I do not think the above is a good way to do in in general.

I think a special rule is needed to tell Mathematica about orthogonality of trig functions, and then ask Integrate to use this rule?  But how to do this?

The question is: Should Mathematica have been able to automatically handle the special case of `n=3` above? If not, what would be the best way to add a rule to tell Integrate to do this?

Comment: Based on one answer already posted, what I have often found is that MMA does not pay attention to `Assumtions` inside `Intégrate`, but does to `Assuming`. I mean, I get the correct result for assumptions by using `Assuming` instead.

Comment: Some of this is explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration)

Comment: See also [this MathGroup thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Oct/msg00119.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the answer:

```
Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]
Normal@Series[%, {n, 3, 0}]  (* evaluate at n -> 3 *)
(* Pi/2 *)
```

I suppose Mathematica should get the right answer, but there's way in which this shows the answer returned by `Integrate` contains the correct answer at `n == 3`.  Algebraic notation is sometimes deficient, and for an analytic object like this result, the power series is probably the best mathematical representation of the object.  The undefined points `n == ±3` of the expression returned by `Integrate` are not even singularities of the series.  (It is to address such a deficiency that the need for the `Sinc` function was felt.)  Thus I think `Series` (also `Limit`) is a mathematically correct way to evaluate the result.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular example, you could try using [`FourierSinCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSinCoefficient):

```
FourierSinCoefficient[Sin[3 x], x, n, FourierParameters->{-1,1}]
```

> 1/2 π DiscreteDelta[-3 + n]

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a bug!

```
I0=Simplify[Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi} ] ](*-((3 Sin[n \[Pi]])/(-9 + n^2))*)
I1=Simplify[Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi} ],Assumptions ->Element[n, Integers]](*0*)
I2=Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n != 3](*-((3 Sin[n \[Pi]])/(-9 + n^2))*)
I3=Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n ==  3](*\[Pi]/2*)
```

The integrals I0,I2,I3 are evaluated as expected whereras I1 gives a wrong result! It looks like the Limit/Singularity n->3 isn't recognized by the Simplify-Command!

Comment: I understand that a singularity cannot be simplified. However, doing `Limit` does solve the problem in `I1`.

Comment: Yes `Limit[I0,n->3]` shows that the solution I0(!) is ok. Nevertheless I1 is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[n_] = Piecewise[{{Integrate[Sin[3 x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}], n == 3}},
  Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Didn't understand the question at first

First, note that to get 0, which is the answer when n≠3, you need to use Assuming instead of Assumptions:

```
ClearAll[x, n]
Assuming[
 Element[n, Integers] && n > 0,
 Integrate[Sin[3 x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}]
 ]
```

Output:

```
0
```

Now the question is why Mathematica fails to notice the special case of n=3. I speculate that Mathematica's ability to recognize the need of a delta function is lacking here. For instance, if I type an integral that is equivalent to the delta function, I just get an error:

```
Integrate[Exp[-I k x], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Output:

```
During evaluation of In[1845]:= Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(-I k x) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.
```

Your case may be another specific case of `Integrate` not identifying opportunities for the delta function. I would perhaps report it as a bug.

Comment: thank you. But I think that is what I wrote. I wanted Mathematica not to give zero for all `n`. I am not sure how your solution handles this special case?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. That is strange that it fails to notice the n=3 case. This seems to qualify as a bug, perhaps submit it to support if you don't get a better answer on SE? You can report it here: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, I am not sure if it is a bug or not. Since this could be by design. i.e. it could be that Mathematica is not designed to detect special cases like this. But I am not sure, that is why I asked.

Comment: Well I think it's fair to call anything that evaluates to an incorrect answer a 'bug', since presumably Mathematica would never be wrong by design. The correct answer would involve a delta function ∂(n-3). I'll update my answer.