# A problem when integrate Cos[n*x]*Cos[k*x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When integrate the indefinite integral *Cos[n*x]*Cos[k*x] about x, where both *k* and *n* are positive integer, the result is *Pi* when *n* equals to *k* and 0 when *n* is unequal to *k*. However, the code

```
sol = Integrate[Cos[n*x]*Cos[k*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && k ∈ Integers && n > 0 && k > 0]
```

gives the result `(k Sin[π k + π n] - n Sin[π k + π n] + 
 k Sin[π k - π n] + n Sin[π k - π n])/(k^2 - n^2)`.
[image]

And then use the Simplify function,

```
Simplify[sol, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && k ∈ Integers && n > 0 && k > 0]
```

gives the result 0. Shouldn't that Integrate returns a Piecewise function like `Piecewise[{{Pi, n == k}, {0, n != k}}]` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is well know issue. One way to handle it is

```
Simplify[ sol, 
 Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && Element[k, Integers] && n > 0 && k > 0 && k != n]

(* 0 *)
```

And

```
Simplify[ Limit[sol, k -> n], 
 Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && Element[k, Integers] && n > 0 && k > 0 && k == n ]

(* Pi *)
```

See

[should-integrate-detect-orthogonality-of-functions-in-the-integrand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165991/should-integrate-detect-orthogonality-of-functions-in-the-integrand)

And

[What assumptions to use to check for orthogonality](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Oct/msg00119.html)

And

[should-integrate-have-given-zero-for-this-integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166958/should-integrate-have-given-zero-for-this-integral)

And

[proper-way-to-simplify-integral-result-in-mathematica-given-integer-constraints](http://proper-way-to-simplify-integral-result-in-mathematica-given-integer-constraints)

And

[usage-of-assuming-for-integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration)

Comment: You can shorten the `Limit` to `Limit[sol, k -> n, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. I am sure you are right. I was only copying what the OP had in there. But good point.