# Remove Abs from Norms of Vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, vector

I have the following norm

```
Norm[{a, b*c}]

(* Sqrt[Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b c]^2] *)
```

How do I remove the `Abs` from it?

```
FullSimplify[Norm[{a, b*c}], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

only kills the first `Abs`

```
Sqrt[a^2 + Abs[b c]^2]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
expr = Norm[{a, b*c}]
```

> Sqrt[Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b c]^2]

Since [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) assumes all its variables to be real, we automatically get what we want.

```
ComplexExpand@expr
```

> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 c^2]

Other methods include

```
Refine[expr, {a > 0, b c > 0}]
```

> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 c^2]

and

```
FunctionExpand[expr, {a > 0, b c > 0}]
```

> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 c^2]

Comment: Thx. Can you explain why `ComplexEpxpand` does it and `Assumptions` does not?

Comment: `ComplexExpand` automatically assumes all its variables to be real.  Other than that, I believe it's just a matter of behind-the-scenes expression manipulation (i.e. I don't know...).  Though this idea reminds me of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/46490) post talking about different ways of assuming things (granted in relation to `Integrate`).

Answer (score 11):

If you have to use `FullSimplify` or `Simplify`, you can use the option [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) to make expressions with `Abs` more costly:

```
FullSimplify[Norm[{a, b*c}], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (100 Count[#, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] +  LeafCount[#] &)]
```

> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 c^2]

Comment: And the reason that `ComplexityFunction` is needed in this case is because `LeafCount /@ {Sqrt[a^2 + Abs[b*c]^2], Sqrt[a^2 + b^2*c^2]}` evaluates to `{14, 15}`, i.e., the apparent simpler form is not simpler.

Comment: @BobHanlon, great point.

Answer (score 5):

Also, for a real number `x`, `Abs[x] = Sqrt[x^2]`

```
Norm[{a, b*c}] /. Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2]

(* Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 c^2] *)
```