# Error in Fourier Method for PDE

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to solve the problem $$u_t=u_{xx}, \ \ \ \ 0<x<\pi  , \ t>0   $$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi ,t)=0, \ \ \ \ t\geq 0$$
$$u(x,0)=\cos x -3\cos(2x)+5\cos(4x), \ \ \ \ 0 \leq x \leq \pi$$
using the formulas of the Fourier method

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Cos[x] - 3*Cos[2*x] + 5*Cos[4*x]
L = π;
l[n_] := (n^2*π^2)/L^2

Y[n_, x_] := Cos[(n*π*x)/L]
d[0] = (Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, L}])/(Integrate[(Y[0, x])^2, {x, 0, L}])
d[n_] =Simplify[ (Integrate[
    f[x]*Y[n, x], {x, 0, L}])/(Integrate[(Y[n, x])^2, {x, 0, L}]),Element[n,Integers]]







v[x_, t_, nmax_] := d[0] + Sum[d[n]*E^(-l[n]*t)*Y[n, x], {n, 1, nmax}]

v[x_, t_, 5]




Plot3D[v[x, t, 10], {x, 0, π}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

but I get a wrong solution, a flat surface.

Why is this happening? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it using Fourier method

\begin{align}
u_{t}  & =u_{xx}\tag{1}\\
u_{x}\left(  0,t\right)    & =0\nonumber\\
u_{x}\left(  \pi,t\right)    & =0\nonumber\\
u\left(  x,0\right)    & =\cos x-3\cos\left(  2x\right)  +5\cos\left(
4x\right)  \nonumber
\end{align}

Using Fourier method, the eigenvalues and eigefunctions for $y^{\prime\prime
}+\lambda y=0$ with B.C. $y^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  =0,y^{\prime}\left(
\pi\right)  =0$ are known to be

```
op = {-y''[x] + NeumannValue[0, True]}
eig = DEigenvalues[op, y[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eigf = Last@DEigensystem[op, y[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence

\begin{align*}
\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)    & =\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \\
\lambda_{n}  & =\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}
\end{align*}

Or for $L=\pi$

\begin{align*}
\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)    & =\cos\left(  nx\right)  \\
\lambda_{n}  & =n^{2}%
\end{align*}

Therefore the solution to the PDE is the Fourier series

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}

And now the goal is to find $b_{n}\left(  t\right)  $ to finish the solution.
Substituting (2) in (1) gives

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(
x\right)
$$

But $\Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)  =-\lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  $ since $\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ is eigenfunction. The above becomes

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)
& =-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}b_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  \\
b_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  +\lambda_{n}%
b_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)    & =0\\
b_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  +\lambda_{n}b_{n}\left(  t\right)    & =0\\
b_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  +n^{2}b_{n}\left(  t\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

This is first oder ode in $b_{n}\left(  t\right)  \,$. Solving gives

$$
b_{n}\left(  t\right)  =C_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}
$$

Substituting the above in (2) gives

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Now $C_{n}$ are found from initial conditions. At $t=0$ the above becomes

\begin{equation}
\cos x-3\cos\left(  2x\right)  +5\cos\left(  4x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}C_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{4}
\end{equation}

For $n=1$

\begin{align*}
\cos x  & =C_{1}\Phi_{1}\left(  x\right)  \\
C_{1}  & =\frac{\cos x}{\Phi_{1}\left(  x\right)  }=\frac{\cos x}{\cos\left(
x\right)  }=1
\end{align*}

For $n=2$

\begin{align*}
-3\cos\left(  2x\right)    & =C_{2}\Phi_{2}\left(  x\right)  \\
C_{2}  & =\frac{-3\cos\left(  2x\right)  }{\Phi_{2}\left(  x\right)  }
=\frac{-3\cos\left(  2x\right)  }{\cos\left(  2x\right)  }=-3
\end{align*}

For $n=4$

\begin{align*}
5\cos\left(  4x\right)    & =C_{4}\Phi_{4}\left(  x\right)  \\
C_{4}  & =5\frac{\cos\left(  4x\right)  }{\Phi_{4}\left(  x\right)  }
=5\frac{\cos\left(  4x\right)  }{\cos\left(  4x\right)  }=5
\end{align*}

Substituting the above in (3) gives

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,t\right)    & =C_{1}e^{-t}\Phi_{1}\left(  x\right)  +C_{2}%
e^{-4t}\Phi_{2}\left(  x\right)  +C_{4}e^{-16t}\Phi_{4}\left(  x\right)  \\
& =e^{-t}\cos\left(  x\right)  -3e^{-4t}\cos\left(  2x\right)  +5e^{-16t}
\cos\left(  4x\right)
\end{align*}

### Verify using Mathematica

```
ClearAll[u, x, t]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]
bc = {(D[u[x, t], x] == 0) /. x -> 0, (D[u[x, t], x] == 0) /. x -> Pi}
ic = u[x, 0] == Cos[x] - 3*Cos[2*x] + 5*Cos[4*x]
DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

animation

```
Animate[Grid[{{Row[{"time=", t0}]}, {Plot[sol /. t -> t0, {x, 0, Pi}, 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> 300]}}], {t0, 
  0, .2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By introducing new function `c[n_] := (Integrate[(Y[n, x])^2, {x, 0, L}])` we can solve this problem as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Cos[x] - 3*Cos[2*x] + 5*Cos[4*x]
L = \[Pi];
l[n_] := (n^2*\[Pi]^2)/L^2

Y[n_, x_] := Cos[(n*\[Pi]*x)/L]; 
c[n_] := (Integrate[(Y[n, x])^2, {x, 0, L}]);
d[0] = (Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, L}])/c[0];
d[n_] := (Integrate[f[x]*Y[n, x], {x, 0, L}])/c[n]
v[x_, t_, nmax_] := d[0] + Sum[d[n]*E^(-l[n]*t)*Y[n, x], {n, 1, nmax}]
```

Now we can evaluate

```
v[x, t, 5]

Out[]= E^-t Cos[x] - 3 E^(-4 t) Cos[2 x] + 5 E^(-16 t) Cos[4 x]
```

Visualization

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[v[x, t, 10] /. {x -> x1, t -> t1}], {x1, 
  0, \[Pi]}, {t1, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "v"}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 2):

It's `Simplify` that's not working properly. If you observe the output of your code carefully, you'll find the line

```
d[n_] =Simplify[ (Integrate[
    f[x]*Y[n, x], {x, 0, L}])/(Integrate[(Y[n, x])^2, {x, 0, L}]),
                Element[n,Integers]]
```

outputs `0`! So the issue boils down to

> ```
> Simplify[(4 n^2 (-92 + 46 n^2 + n^4) Sin[
>    n π])/((-64 + 84 n^2 - 21 n^4 + n^6) (2 n π + Sin[2 n π])), 
>  n ∈ Integers]
> ```
>
> outputs `0`.

This seems to be a **possible issue** of `Simplify`. As mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/1871):

> `Simplify` *et al.* return "generic results", so e.g. `Sin[ k π]/k`
> will simplify to 0 if told that `k` is an integer.
>
> ```
> Simplify[ Sin[ k π]/k, Assumptions-> k ∈ Integers]                 
>
> (* Out[4]= 0 *)
> ```

In any case, I'd suggest reporting it to WRI.

Luckily, if you just want to circumvent the problem, removing the `n ∈ Integers` is enough.