# Issue evaluating integral: seems to lead to incorrect answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to compute the integral

$$ F(i, j) = \int_0^1 \phi_i(x) \phi_j(x)  dx, \quad \mbox{where}~~ \phi_k(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin\Big(\frac{2 k - 1}{2} \pi x\Big) $$

The integer $k \geq 1$. The answer should be $F(i,j) = \delta_{ij}$
so that $F(i,i) = 1$ for all integers $i \geq 1$ and $F(i,j) = 0$
for positive integers $i \neq j$.

The answer I get from Mathematica is wrong:

```
In[27]:= EigFun[j_, x_] = Sqrt[2] * Sin[Pi * x * (2*j - 1)/2]


Out[27]= Sqrt[2] Sin[1/2 (-1 + 2 j) \[Pi] x]

In[29]:= 
ExpVal[i_, j_] = Integrate[EigFun[i, x] * EigFun[j, x], {x, 0, 1}]

Out[29]= (
Sin[(i - j) \[Pi]]/(i - j) - 
 Sin[(-1 + i + j) \[Pi]]/(-1 + i + j))/\[Pi]

In[30]:= FullSimplify[%29, 
 Assumptions -> {i >= 1 && j >= 1 && i \[Element] Integers && 
    j \[Element] Integers}]

Out[30]= 0
```

Is there an easy fix for this? Or what is the explanation for this issue?

Comment: Please add code as text instead of an image.

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: There is no easy fix (except providing explicit numbers for i and j before integration).
If you want to get `KroneckerDelta[i,j]` as result, you could send an email to support@wolfram.com and complain about a misleading result for `Integrate[Sqrt[2]*
     Sin[(1/2)*(2*i - 1)*Pi*x]*
     Sqrt[2]*Sin[(1/2)*
         (2*j - 1)*Pi*x], 
   {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 
     i \[Element] Integers && j \[Element] Integers,
   GenerateConditions -> True]`.
I am sure WRI is aware of these subtle issues.
BTW: ChatGPT gets it wrong, too ...

Comment: Can you explain why "there is no easy fix" ... this not really a strange/complicated integral?

Comment: Well, maybe there is. Please call Wolfram. I just did not find an "easy fix" .
Maybe you try other systems? Like Maple, or Sympy or so?

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19833/1871

Comment: Limits of  indefinites have to be taken explicitely $$Limit[ Sin[(i - j) \[Pi]]/(i - j), i -> j]  -> \pi$$

Answer (score 6):

The integral behaves reasonably well if one takes limits.

```
eij = Integrate[EigFun[i, x]*EigFun[j, x], {x, 0, 1}];
limsameij = Limit[eij, j -> i]
Simplify[limsameij, Assumptions -> Element[i, Integers]]

(* Out[324]= 1 + Sin[2 i \[Pi]]/((-1 + 2 i) \[Pi])

Out[325]= 1 *)

limdiffij = Limit[eij, j -> i + k, Assumptions -> k >= 1]
Simplify[limdiffij, Assumptions -> Element[{i, k}, Integers] && k >= 1]

(* Out[326]= (
Sin[k \[Pi]]/k - Sin[(-1 + 2 i + k) \[Pi]]/(-1 + 2 i + k))/\[Pi]

Out[327]= 0 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

EigFun[j_, x_] = Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*x*(2*j - 1)/2];

ExpVal[i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] = 
 Evaluate@Assuming[{i, j} ∈ PositiveIntegers,
   Piecewise[{
     {Integrate[EigFun[i, x]*EigFun[j, x], {x, 0, 1}], i != j},
     {Integrate[EigFun[i, x]^2, {x, 0, 1}], i == j}}]]

(* Piecewise[{{0, i != j}, {1, i == j}}, 0] *)
```

or, more compactly,

```
ExpVal[i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] = 
 Evaluate@Assuming[{i, j} ∈ PositiveIntegers,
   Piecewise[{
       {Integrate[EigFun[i, x]*EigFun[j, x], {x, 0, 1}], i != j},
       {Integrate[EigFun[i, x]^2, {x, 0, 1}], i == j}}] // 
     Simplify]

(* Piecewise[{{0, i != j}}, 1] *)
```

Comment: Sure, of course it works if you explicitly tell it that the indices are equal (or not). But the question is: if one is to trust integral results on Mathematica, one would hope for at least an error message rather than Mathematica confidently returning 0 (in other cases, one may not actually be able to easily calculate the integral by hand whereas Mathematica could...)