# Integral of complex exponential with assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I feel confident this problem has been posed before but alas I cannot find it.

```
Clear[k, m];
Assuming[Element[{k, m}, NonNegativeIntegers], 
 Integrate[E^(2 Pi I (k - m) t), {t, 0, 1}]]
```

yields `0`, which is only valid when $k \neq m$.  The answer should instead be a `KroneckerDelta` with indices $k$ and $m$.

How do I ensure the case $k=m$ is also included in the result?

Comment: Mathematica gives result which is generic. You could always add extra assumption. Here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMyaB.png)  which gives zero only when `k!=m` and gives 1 when `k=m` but I do not know if there is way to make Integrate do that on its own.

Comment: @Nasser:  Thanks.  The result $0$ isn't exactly "generic," but instead the typical case.  I realize I could split the cases into $k=m$ and $k \neq m$, but I would have thought that *Mathematica* could do this explicitly.

Comment: Should be a Kronecker delta, not a Dirac delta.

Comment: On 13.3.0.0 with `Integrate[Exp[2 \[Pi] I (k - m) t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {k \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers, 
   m \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers}]` I get a non-zero expression (`-((I (-1 + E^(2 I (k - m) \[Pi])))/(2 (k - m) \[Pi]))`) which exhibits the appropriate behavior (assuming `Limit` is used for the $k=m$ case).

Comment: Using `FullSimplify` on that result with the same assumptions reduces it to `0` though.

Comment: `int[k_, m_] = Assuming[{k, m} \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers, Piecewise[{{Assuming[k == m , Integrate[E^(2*Pi*I*(k - m)*t), {t, 0, 1}]], {k, m} \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers && k == m }, {Assuming[k != m , Integrate[E^(2*Pi*I*(k - m)*t), {t, 0, 1}]], {k, m} \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers && k != m}}]]`

Comment: Thanks... helpful... but again essentially a solution "by hand."

Comment: Another "by hand" solution: integrate over the reals and then specialize on the integers. `Integrate[Exp[2π*I*q*t], {t,0,1}] == Sinc[2π*q] + I*Sinc[π*q]*Sin[π*q] // FullSimplify` gives `True`. The imaginary part is zero $\forall q\in\mathbb{Z}$. The real part is 1 for $q=0$ and zero for all other integers.

Comment: Here is [one older version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration) among several others.