# Integrate has issues when integrating the general form of a trigonometric integral but not specific instances

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve with Mathematica the following integral for $m$ a positive integer

$$s=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\sin^4(\pi\nu m)}{m^2\sin^2(\pi\nu)}\mathrm{d}\nu$$

which should yield $1/(4m)$ (I already know the solution but want to practice with Mathematica which I use too sparingly). If I solve any specific instance, I get the right result, e.g.

```
Integrate[Sin[Pi \[Nu] 128]^4/(128 Sin[Pi \[Nu]])^2, {\[Nu], 0, 1/2}]
```

yields $1/512$. However, if I try to solve the general case with

```
Integrate[Sin[Pi \[Nu] m]^4/(m Sin[Pi \[Nu]])^2, {\[Nu], 0, 1/2}, Assumptions -> m \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

or with

```
Integrate[Sin[Pi \[Nu] m]^4/(m Sin[Pi \[Nu]])^2, {\[Nu], -1/2, 1/2}, PrincipalValue->True, Assumptions -> m \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

I get a more convoluted expression that yields infinities when substituting an integer value for $m$.

I thought that the problem might be due to the singularity at $\nu=0$ and also tried to integrate with a lower limit different from zero and then take the limit afterward, but it didn't work. The same starting from the indefinite integral.

Any tips on how to improve the solution?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19833/1871

Answer (score 8):

> that yields infinities when substituting an integer value for m

You need to use Limit.

```
integrand = Sin[Pi *v*m]^4/(m*Sin[Pi*v])^2
anti = Integrate[integrand /. m -> 128, {v, 0, 1/2}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[m, PositiveIntegers]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
anti = Integrate[integrand, {v, 0, 1/2}, Assumptions -> Element[m, PositiveIntegers]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Limit[anti, m -> 128]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not use limit, you get

```
anti /. m -> 128
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looking at your and Mariusz's answers it seems that there's no easy way to guide `Integrate` or `Limit` to directly yield the solution $1/(4m)$. I always find it hard to understand these Mathematica's idiosyncrasies...

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano **Mathematica** is not a **magic** box that'll spit out a solution to any problem. Maple **2023** cannot do it, either for general `m`.

Answer (score 6):

Easy way:

```
S = Table[Integrate[Sin[Pi  \[Nu]  m]^4/(m  Sin[Pi  \[Nu]])^2, {\[Nu], 0, 1/2}], {m, 1, 10}];
FindSequenceFunction[S, m]

(*1/(4 m)*)
```

Hard way:

```
S = Integrate[Sin[Pi  \[Nu]  m]^4/(m  Sin[Pi  \[Nu]])^2 // TrigReduce // 
Expand, {\[Nu], 0, 1/2}, Assumptions -> m > 0] // FullSimplify

(*(1/(16 m^2 \[Pi]))I E^(-2 I m \[Pi]) (1 - 
 4 E^(2 I m \[Pi]) m \[Pi] (2 Cot[m \[Pi]] - Cot[2 m \[Pi]]) + 
2 m PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - m] - 2 m PolyGamma[0, -m] - 
4 E^(I m \[Pi]) (1 + m PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - m/2] - 
  m PolyGamma[0, -(m/2)]) + 
 E^(4 I m \[Pi]) (1 + 2 m PolyGamma[0, m] - 
  2 m PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + m]) - 
 4 E^(3 I m \[Pi]) (1 + m PolyGamma[0, m/2] - 
  m PolyGamma[0, (1 + m)/2]))*)

FullSimplify[S, Assumptions -> m \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
(*Indeterminate*)

{Table[Limit[S, m -> w], {w, 1, 10}] // FullSimplify, Table[1/(4 m), {m, 1, 10}]} // TableForm
```